# In Kafka, why we don't have parallelism while consuming a partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Here is my understanding about consuming information from a topic in Kafka.

A consumer group is responsible for reading information from a single topic.
If a topic has 5 partitions and if there are five consumers in the consumer group, each one reads information from one whole partition.
If I add another consumer in the consumer group, the newly added consumer is going to be in idle state.

Instead of placing the new consumer in idle state, why Kafak does not allow consuming info from a partition which is already consumed by a different consumer ?
If this happend, there will be more parallelism.

So in jist: In one consumer consumer group, why Kafka does not allow more than one consumers reading information from a single partition  ?

Thanks!

Comment: _consuming info from a partition which is already consumed by a different consumer_ - What exactly is your use case for processing an event multiple times? And if that is what you want, why use only one consumer group?

Comment: It is not processing a single events multiple times.. It is about sharing the workload. 
Let assume that there are two consumers C1 and C2 consuming information from a topic P. If a piece of message is provided to one consumer, then the same might not be provided to another consumer. Why this is not happening in Kafka ? If this is allowed, there will be high parallelism which eventually increases the throughput.

Comment: How/Why would messages be split across separate offsets? A single offset of a TopicPartition will be polled by only one consumer in a group. If you want to process that again, then you call `seek` or disable commits and restart the poll call.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly, because of the challenges in managing the offset, this feature is not available. Am I correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by challenges or feature. Every time a producer calls send method, the offset gets incremented and the whole record is at that offset. Therefore, when consumed, no two consumers (of the same group) will see or be able to process different parts of one record

Answer (score 1):

In many use cases, kafka partitions are also used to provide ordering on specific keys. For e.g. while processing events for some users we might want to process events in parallel overall but in order for a user (user update events can be processed only after user creation event). In such scenarios, we would use user id as partition key so that all event for that user go to one specific partition and hence can be processed in order.

If this is not your use case, you can always read events in bulk in your consumer and process them in parallel manner.

Comment: I have rephrased my question in in my comment. Perhaps, this is more clearer on what I am requesting for..